# gnuplot overlay same time different day plots?

Tags: date, time, gnuplot, overlay

I have two data files of two days and same time

date1data.csv

```
2018.02.03.18:23,4
2018.02.03.19:23,22
2018.02.03.20:23,12
2018.02.03.21:23,3
2018.02.03.22:23,16
```

date2data.csv

```
2018.02.04.18:23,1
2018.02.04.19:23,5
2018.02.04.20:23,22
2018.02.04.21:23,5
2018.02.04.22:23,14
```

If I plot them I get this plot where the data is plotted one day after another.
[image]
How can I plot them with respect to the time only and not the date so that they overlay at the same time? Is this possible? I dont want to plot them in multiple windows.

Thats the code I used for plotting:

```
set datafile separator ","
set terminal pngcairo size 500,200 enhanced font 'Verdana,10' linewidth 1
set output 'test.png'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y.%m.%d.%H:%M"
set format x "%H:%M"
plot 'date1data.csv' using 1:2 w lines lw 2 t "day1", 'date2data.csv' using 1:2 w lines lw 2 t "day2"
```

Comment: The additional dot between date and time is a bit unfortunate. Makes you need to resort to some tricks to just ignore the date part.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `using 1:2` with a function that drops the date part of the time string that is column 1:

```
set timefmt "%H:%M"
f(v) = substr(stringcolumn(v),12,16)
plot 'date1data.csv' using (f(1)):2 w lines lw 2 t "day1",\
     'date2data.csv' using (f(1)):2 w lines lw 2 t "day2"
```

[image]

Comment: Okay and that 'stringcolumn(v),12,16' cuts out from 12th to 16th char of the date?

Comment: Do you know how to do your way with bin in gnuplot? Lets say I have multiple files that contain only a date and I do a bin plot:
`binwidth = 3600  #30 second bin
bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width)
plot '...' using (bin(f(1),binwidth)):(1.0) smooth frequency w lines
`
How would I tell the bin to use the time only? Or should I ask that in a separate question?

Comment: `substr(string,from,to)` takes the characters from *string* between the *from* and *to* indexes inclusive (with 1 being the 1st char). I'm not sure I understand your second comment, so please start a new post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses the `stats` command to find the earliest time in the two data files, and shifts the times of the second file so that aligns with the earliest time in the first file. We have to work around a limitations of the `stats` command because it does not work in timedata mode, but we can work around that by doing the time-to-seconds conversion ourselves:

```
set datafile separator ","
fmt = "%Y.%m.%d.%H:%M"
stats "date1data.csv" u (strptime(fmt,strcol(1)))
t1min = STATS_min
stats "date2data.csv" u (strptime(fmt,strcol(1)))
t2min = STATS_min

set xdata time
set format x "%H:%M"
plot 'date1data.csv' using (strptime(fmt,strcol(1))):2 w lines lw 2 t "day1", \
     'date2data.csv' using (strptime(fmt,strcol(1))-t2min+t1min):2 w lines lw 2 t "day2"
```

[image]
This approach has the advantage that it should work even if the data crosses date boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the date part from your data by subtracting midnight:

```
t(x) = x - 24*3600*(floor(x/(24*3600))

plot dataf1 us (t($1)):2, dataf2 us (t($1)):s
```

This actually works 100% correctly because unix time ignores leap seconds, your computer clock just adjusts itself when one occors.